# Hibernate OGM Neo4j (5.0 ) Wildfly 10 Error. Provider org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmIntegrator not a subtype

Tags: hibernate, jpa, neo4j, wildfly, hibernate-ogm

I am getting this error while deployment of ear .

```
org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."test.ear/server.war#graphdb": java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmIntegrator not a subtype
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)


Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmIntegrator not a subtype
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:324)
at org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:40)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:213)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildBootstrapServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:288)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:161)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:34)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:165)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:160)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135)
at org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernateOgmPersistence.java:96)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:318)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$1100(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:167)
... 7 more
```

And my persistence xml is

```
<persistence-unit name="graphdb" transaction-type="JTA">
    <!-- Use Hibernate OGM provider: configuration will be transparent -->
    <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
    <class>com.healthpray.persistence.entities.User</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
            value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform" />
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="neo4j_embedded" />
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.neo4j.database_path" value="/home/manju/testdb" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Can any one please whats the issue ? . I tried removing the JTA provider also.

Wildfly - 10.0
JPA -2.1
Java - 8
Hibernate  - 5.0.0.Beta1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was not working because Wildfly trying to load different version of hibernate. So binary conflict.

I disabled JPA subsystem in `standalone.xml`. Now its working fine.